# ARM Template for Redis Cache failing to deploy

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-rm-template

I am trying to deploy Redis Cache using an ARM Template but it keeps failing with the following error:

> {"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment
>   operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details.
>   Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage
>   details.","details":[{"code":"BadRequest","message":"{\r\n \"error\":
>   {\r\n \"code\": \"LinkedInvalidPropertyId\",\r\n \"message\":
>   \"Property id 'GET-PREREQ-existingDiagnosticsStorageAccountId' at path
>   'properties.storageAccountId' is invalid. Expect fully qualified
>   resource Id that start with '/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}' or
>   '/providers/{resourceProviderNamespace}/'.\"\r\n }\r\n}"}]}

Scoured resources online but I'm unable to figure out what exactly is going wrong. The Redis Cache resource does get created but the deployment isn't completely successful. The following seems to be failing:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFwqY.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLk68.jpg

azuredeployredis.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "redisCacheName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "defaultRedisCacheName",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the Azure Redis Cache to create."
      }
    },
    "redisCacheSKU": {
      "type": "string",
      "allowedValues": [
        "Basic",
        "Standard",
        "Premium"
      ],
      "defaultValue": "Standard",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The pricing tier of the new Azure Redis Cache."
      }
    },
    "redisCacheFamily": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "C",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The family for the sku."
      },
      "allowedValues": [
        "C",
        "P"
      ]
    },
    "redisCacheCapacity": {
      "type": "int",
      "allowedValues": [
        0,
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5,
        6
      ],
      "defaultValue": 1,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The size of the new Azure Redis Cache instance. "
      }
    },
    "enableNonSslPort": {
      "type": "bool",
      "defaultValue": false,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "A boolean value that indicates whether to allow access via non-SSL ports."
      }
    },
    "diagnosticsEnabled": {
      "type": "bool",
      "defaultValue": false,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "A value that indicates whether diagnostics should be saved to the specified storage account."
      }
    },
    "existingDiagnosticsStorageAccountId": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Existing storage account for diagnostics."
      }
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "name": "[parameters('redisCacheName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Cache/Redis",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "enableNonSslPort": "[parameters('enableNonSslPort')]",
        "sku": {
          "capacity": "[parameters('redisCacheCapacity')]",
          "family": "[parameters('redisCacheFamily')]",
          "name": "[parameters('redisCacheSKU')]"
        }
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "apiVersion": "2017-05-01-preview",
          "type": "Microsoft.Cache/redis/providers/diagnosticsettings",
          "name": "[concat(parameters('redisCacheName'), '/Microsoft.Insights/', parameters('redisCacheName'))]",
          "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.Cache/Redis/', parameters('redisCacheName'))]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "storageAccountId": "[parameters('existingDiagnosticsStorageAccountId')]",
            "metrics": [
              {
                "timeGrain": "AllMetrics",
                "enabled": "[parameters('diagnosticsEnabled')]",
                "retentionPolicy": {
                  "days": 90,
                  "enabled": "[parameters('diagnosticsEnabled')]"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

azuredeployredis.parameters.json:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "redisCacheName": {
      "value": "xyz-redis-cache"
    },
    "existingDiagnosticsStorageAccountId": {
      "value": "GET-PREREQ-existingDiagnosticsStorageAccountId"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: As the error message indicates the `storageAccountId` needs to be a complete `resource id` of the storage account instead of `GET-PREREQ-existingDiagnosticsStorageAccountId` as indicated by your params file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean, the error clearly says you need to pass in resourceId, not resource name to the properties.storageAccountId. it should look like this:

```
/subscriptions/guid/resourceGroups/rgname/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/storagename
```

you can use `resourceId()` function to calculate that:

```
resourceId('subscriptionId', 'resourceGroupname', 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', 'storageaccountname')
```

subscriptionid and resourcegroupname are only needed if storage account is in different subscription and\or resource group

Comment: Thank you! Seemed to have overlooked this for some reason. I followed a github template and didn't see this.